# Stanford NLP/NER - how to use extractors and classifiers?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction

The demo file that comes with Stanford's Named Entity Recognition package shows 
examples of classifying sentences. The outputs options are Strings such as:

```
"I eat apples with Michael and Jordan on mondays"
```

=>

```
 "I eat apples with <PERSON>Michael</PERSON> and 
<PERSON>Jordan</PERSON> on <DATE>mondays</DATE>"
```

or a map of classifications per word.

Is there a method that returns a map of classification to a list of entities?

EG:

```
{
  PERSON : ["Michael", "Peter"]
  DATE : ["mondays"]
}
```

Comment: just parse the strings yourself, grepping the tags :)

Comment: was wondering whether there is a more elegant way of doing this

Comment: Short answer: no.  Long answer: there are several programming interfaces for various languages, use those if you don't like the output format

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal bash script that will do this as a postprocessing :

```
echo "I eat apples with <PERSON>Michael</PERSON> and <PERSON>Jordan</PERSON> on <DATE>mondays</DATE>"
| grep -Eo '<([^>/]*)>[^<]*'
| awk -F '>' '{nes[$1]=nes[$1]","$2;} END {for(t in nes) print tolower(t)":{"nes[t]"}";}'
| sed 's/:{,/:{/' | tr -d '<'
```

using this you'll obtain lists as for your example :

```
date:{mondays}
person:{Michael,Jordan}
```

You'll probably want to handle multiple entries ("uniq" or count them?).